# $_GET "+" sign causing in mysql search

Tags: php, javascript, get

I have a form that inputs a $_GET and pops this into a MySQL query. It works roughly as I'd expect however:

When searching for an item that has spaces in, the $_GET replaces those spaces with "+".

This is where it gets hard to explain....

The initial query works fine and those items with the space as well are returned from the database no problems.

However:

I then have a pop-up calculations window that references to a different php function that concatenates the pages $_GET onto the $_GET of the new url.

It is at this stage that the "+" triggers the end of the url and doesn't display anything.

For example:

This is the $_GET `?dialstring=&groupSelect=uk+vodafone`
However the popup gets the $_GET as `?dialstring=&groupSelect=uk`

I think it may be the JS popup code that breaks the $_GET which is as follows:

```
function modalcalc(){ 
      $('<div>').dialog({
      title:    'Calculator',
      height: '350', 
      width:    '400',
      open: function ()
        {
        $(this).load('<?=base_url();?>ratesheet/calculator/<?=$this->uri->segment(3);?>/?dialstring=<?=$_GET['dialstring']?>&groupSelect=<?=$_GET['groupSelect']?>');
        },         
modal: true 
});
return false;
}`
```

For the sake of the rest of the massive function I need/Wish to keep it a $_GET as a $_POST doesnt seem to be able to do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<?=$_GET['dialstring']?>` by `<?=rawurlencode($_GET['dialstring']);?>` and `<?=$_GET['groupSelect']?>` by `<?=rawurlencode($_GET['groupSelect']);?>`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rawurlencode` instead of `urlencode` when you generate your query strings.

It will use `%20` instead of `+` (RFC 3986), which is what PHP expects.

Alternately, I you are running PHP >= 5.4 you can specify `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` as the enc_type argument in  [http-build-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: Sorry but if you could explain at what stage to use rawurlencode would appreciate it. in controller or view where I am putting it into the JS URL?

Comment: when you build your query string.